# openoffice calc occurrences of combination

Tags: count, libreoffice, openoffice.org, calc

I would like a formula for open office calc to get the number of occurrences for two or more columns in a single row. But have no idea how to do it. I can just use COUNTIF for a single value, but it does not seem to work with multiple values. I would like the data to remain in it's own column.

eg

```
34, 64 = 2
77, 35 = 0
77, 34 = 1
```

.

```
a   b   c   d
1   77  34  64
2   75  34  64
```

Answer (score 0):

Move the original data to start in row 2 for convenience. Then in `E1` and `F1`, enter what we want to find, which is `34` and `64`.

Now enter the following formula in `E2`, which determines whether the values occur in the second row.

```
=IFNA(IF(MATCH(E$1;$A2:$C2;0)+1=MATCH(F$1;$A2:$C2;0);1;0);0)
```

Drag this formula down to `E3` to handle the next row, and keep dragging if there are more rows of data.

Finally in `E4`, add the results from each row to get the total number of occurrences: `=SUM(E2:E3)`.

Next, enter `77` and `35` in column H and I and then copy and paste the formulas. Do the same for the third pair as well.

[image: total number of occurrences 2, 0, 1]

Documentation: [MATCH function](https://wiki.openoffice.org/wiki/Documentation/How_Tos/Calc:_MATCH_function)